# Passing Enums in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, enums

I am having issues with using the Enums in WCF. As soon as it returned the object with enum value, I got an exception. I did a lot of search and found numerous questions related to the problem I have. I did follow those solutions but is not working. (I changed those Enum type to int and it worked. I got an exception as soon as I changed it to the Enum. I believe that the Enum is causing the problem). Please help.

I have the following:

```
    [DataContract]
    public enum UserRoleEnum:int
    {
       [EnumMember]
       SystemAdmin = 1,                

       [EnumMember]
       Waiter = 2
    }

    [DataContract()]
    public partial class UserInfoDTO
    {
        [DataMember()]
        public Int32 UserID { get; set; }

        [DataMember()]
        public String UserName { get; set; }

        [DataMember()]
        public byte[] Password { get; set; }

        [DataMember()]
        public String UserStatusName { get; set; }

        [DataMember()]
        public UserRoleEnum UserRole { get; set; }
        .
        .
        .
     }
```

In my service contact,

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(UserRoleEnum))]
public interface IUserService
{
    [OperationContract()]
    UserDTO[] GetUser(int userID);

}
```

I am getting the following error (which I concluded that Enum was causing it)

{"The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.9759247'."}

Comment: error you are getting ?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Please add sample client and service implementation code as well.

Comment: In your interface where you are using Enum? And I guess you are passing Enum to GetUser and hence getting error.

Comment: replace `EnumMember` with `DataMember`

Comment: @Amit yes You are correct. UserDTO has a DataMember called UerRole which is UserRoleEnum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by making the enums to start at 0 instead of 1.

```
 [DataContract]
 public enum UserRoleEnum:int
 {
    [EnumMember]
    SystemAdmin = 0,                

    [EnumMember]
    Waiter = 1
 }
```

and I tried not setting any values for enum as below:

```
 [DataContract]
 public enum UserRoleEnum:int
 {
    [EnumMember]
    SystemAdmin,                

    [EnumMember]
    Waiter
 }
```

Both of them work. But I found a post that setting enums to 0 does not work (see the link) http://haishibai.blogspot.com/2010/12/quick-tip-enum-types-in-wcf.html

Can anyone explain or confirm that enums to be started at 0 (instead of 1 in WCF) and why my results are inconsistent with the post (maybe the blogger is incorrect)?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding [Serializable] above the [DataContract] in your Enum? Might be having trouble with serialization  I'm not sure though. Please update with the result.

Comment: datacontracts are serializable.

Comment: @KaanBoz I tried as you suggested and did not work.I tried the following:                                                                                      [Serializable] 
    [DataContract]
    public enum UserRoleEnum:int
    {
       [EnumMember]
       SystemAdmin = 1,                

       [EnumMember]
       Waiter = 2
    }

Comment: @ShamirDaj Thanks for the reply. Sorry about the result.